# Can I add Active Directory properties to be loaded in UserPrincipal?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, userprincipal

Using the DirectorySearcher we can specify which properties can be loaded when searching in the AD.

```
    DirectorySearcher dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
    dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-PrincipalName");
```

I'm interested in loading **msDS-PrincipalName** property. Is this possible?

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: I don't want to make unnecessary queries to the AD, because it contains tons of records, which will slow down the performance. Part of the application is built around the UserPrincipal and making a call to the AD for one property is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to help anynone but I found an alternative to the msDS-PrincipalName.

```
    userPrincipal.Sid.Translate(typeof (NTAccount)).ToString()
```

This will return the same thing the property mentioned above does which is:
 **DOMAIN\Username**